# DigitalOcean: Various operations (ssh into droplet, git pull to droplet) time out intermittently

Tags: digital-ocean

I'm new to cloud/IaaS stuff, and this seems like a weird issue, so I'm not entirely sure what info to provide, sorry.

I'm playing around with writing my first Ansible playbooks to configure a test droplet.

One task in my playbook is `ansible.builtin.command: git clone --bare [repo] [target]`. This task works sometimes, but usually, it hangs for a couple minutes and then times out. Similarly, ssh-ing into the droplet (either via `doctl compute ssh`, or via executing the Ansible playbook) sometimes goes through, but usually times out.

If I run the playbook enough times, eventually it gets lucky and everything executes correctly. I am changing nothing between attempts, literally just running the command again. Same for manual ssh via `doctl`.

I thought that maybe the server can't handle the load (I am using the cheapest option, $4), but looking at `htop` there seems to be plenty of unused RAM and CPU.

Both the machine I'm ssh-ing from and the droplet are on Ubuntu Server Ubuntu 22.04.

Rebuilding the droplet also doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm tagging this with [tag:digital-ocean] and not [tag:ansible] because it seems unrelated to Ansible. I'm only mentioning the Ansible stuff for context

Comment: Have you tried to use ssh directly without the doctl? Are you running in the same issue when trying it directly?